# Browser loads up my PHP file rather than sending an email

Tags: php, email

I want the form to send the contents to my email, instead it's just displaying my php code in a new window, can anyone help? here is the code:

Index

```
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
  Name: <br><input type="text" name="name"><br><p>
  Request: <br><textarea name="request"></textarea><p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send!">
</form>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$request = $_POST['request'];

$to = "myemail@email.co.uk";
$subject = "It's just a test";
$body = "This is just a test to see if things are working okay \n\n $request";

mail ($to,$subject,$body);

echo "Message sent!"
?>
```

Comment: Replace quotes before first `<form>` tag and after last `</form>` tag. Also, remove (or comment) `**PHP**`.

Comment: vicbyte - what do you mean? tell me more about that please. I'm new to this so treat me like an idiot haha.

Comment: Is that `**PHP**` supposed to be a comment in your post or does it actually exist in the php file? Do the quotes around the `form` actually exist in your code or are thay an attempt to post us a code fragment

Comment: Try reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting Fix what I assume are Woopsies in your question, and then we can get down to business

Comment: let me have a wild guess you are running this code in localhost??

Comment: @xitas yes, locahhost

Answer (score 0):

Few tips for beginners

1. First Configure your Xampp form send email [How to configure XAMPP to send mail from localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost)
2. Check if the data is coming to send.php by `print_r($_POST)`
3. Follow this tutorial for sending email [from here](https://www.phpjabbers.com/make-contact-form-and-send-email-in-php-php21.html)

Comment: not a proper answer but this will help you. after that any query you can ask me in comment

Comment: okay so what will happen if i replace the email address with a file on my computer, will it send the data there? I am just using sublime text, are there any other programs I need?

Comment: i don't think so email is different protocol and sending data into file is different.

Comment: if you want write data into file you can use this https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Comment: using good practice is another debate that i am going into

Comment: `print_f($_POST)` ???? DO you mean `print_r()`

Comment: @riggsfolly yes my bad

Comment: @KieranLythgoe update if not solved